# Fetch DayOfWeek value from asp label

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a ASP Label lblweekoff.Text and its Value could be combination of any 2 weekdays like Sun,Sat/Sun,Mon/Mon,Tue,etc., And I want to get the DayOfWeek value for the 2 weekdays split by comma to check with a date textbox txtdate.Text.

For example,

Lets say I have the below value for the label

```
lblweekoff.Text = "Sun,Sat";
txtDate.Text = "30/3/2019";
var dayColumns = new[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
DateTime weekday = Convert.ToDateTime(lblweekoff.Text);
var weekoff = dayColumns[(int)weekday.DayOfWeek];
DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
if(Date.DayOfWeek == weekoff)
{
    //some code
}
else
{
    //some code
}
```

So I want to check whether the `DayOfWeek` of the date selected on the textbox `txtDate.Text` is equal to that of one of the two `DayOfWeeks` value separated by comma `Sun,Sat` as shown on the label `lblweekoff.Text` and proceed further according to that.

How can I get this done? Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Labels aren't input controls, they display what you tell them to. This means you *already* know what the day, date values are. Instead of converting the dates you already know into strings and then trying to get back the dates, use `DateTime.ToString()` to create strings from those dates, eg `DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd")` or `var date1=DateTime.Today.AddDays(3); txtDate.Text=date1.ToString("d")`

Comment: You usually setting label based on some value - use that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have converted all controls into string, you need to changed that to your control again.

```
    string lblweekoff = "Sun,Sat";
    string txtDate = "30/Mar/2019"; // you might need to format this date 

    var dayColumns = new[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    var offDay = lblweekoff.Split(',').ToList();
    DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate);
    if (offDay.Contains(Date.ToString("ddd")))// weekend
    {
        //some code
    }
    else
    {
        //some code
    }
```

Comment: The enumeration from  DayOfWeek enumeration are not localized. While `ToString()` is.

Answer (score 1):

First, I didn't quite get what you are asking but here is something that may work for you.

You can get today:

```
string day = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString();
lblweekoff.Text = day;
```

End you can pick other one random,

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int day2= rnd.Next(0, 6);
lblweekoff.Text =lblweekoff.Text + ","+dayColumns[rnd];
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: `I didn't quite get what you are asking` If you didn't understood you should not suggest an answer - this might lead OP to wrong direction and wrong solution. Your answer is an example, because OP not asking how to convert day of week to string, but opposite - get day of week from string.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string lblweekoff = "Sun,Sat";
        string txtDate = "3/30/2019";// need format "m/dd/yyyy"
        var dayColumns = new[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
        List<string> weekday = lblweekoff.Split(',').ToList();
        if( dayColumns.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate).ToString("ddd")))
        {

        }
```